# Create new array with unique values from existing array

Tags: bash, array

I'm trying to create a new variable array out of the unique values that are in another array but I'm not getting the desired result.

**Original Array**

```
# echo ${owner[*]}
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 0a452389-5ed2-e46f-ad15-cc538c82650d 4232f23d-ed48-4b14-c0ea-aa911fd24920 8ee1b05f-2473-4c37-bfc5-ae393921b939
```

**Command I'm using**

```
uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${owner[@]}" | sort -u))
```

**Issue** (It's storing all the unique values as a single value under index 0)

```
# echo ${uniq[0]}
0a452389-5ed2-e46f-ad15-cc538c82650d
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
4232f23d-ed48-4b14-c0ea-aa911fd24920
8ee1b05f-2473-4c37-bfc5-ae393921b939
e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb
# echo ${uniq[1]}

#
```

Anyone know a better way of grabbing the unique values from this array?

Using bash on SmartOS (Similar to Solaris)

**EDIT**

I've tried the following as well which will store each value under it's own index number but it does not remove the duplicate values:

```
uniq=($(printf "%s " "${owner[@]}" | sort -u))
```

Comment: Your results suggest that your shell's `IFS` variable does not include newline - have you modified `IFS`? what version of bash is it?

Comment: Off-topic: Are you using Joyent?  (Since you mention SmartOS.)

Comment: Damnit.  I am setting the IFS in my script and think I may have forgot to change it back during testing.  If I just unset IFS will that revert it to default or do you know how I could?

Comment: @Wildcard yes I am.

Comment: Cool.  For resetting IFS, that's really a separate question, but default value should be restored by `IFS=$' \t\n'`  (That's a space, tab, newline.)

Comment: Another option might be to use `mapfile` instead of (implicitly) relying on the value of `IFS` e.g. `mapfile -t uniq < <(printf "%s\n" "${owner[@]}" | sort -u)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${owner[@]}" | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '))
```

Should do it.

Or, as noted in a comment, modify your IFS.

Comment: Why do you need the `tr` near the end?

Comment: @smac89 see comments under the question post.  In general you probably don't, but in this specific case the Original Poster had set IFS to a custom value.

Comment: You could also use `xargs`: `uniq=($(printf "%s\n" "${owner[@]}" | sort -u | xargs))`

Answer (score 2):

Your use of a `echo "${owner[*]}"` makes that **one** long string.

You should have used `printf '%s\n' "${owner[@]}"`.

If an space (or a new line) is the delimiter of the strings you pasted in your question, we can recover the original array with (copy and paste from your post)

```
$ owner=(390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb 0a452389-5ed2-e46f-ad15-cc538c82650d 4232f23d-ed48-4b14-c0ea-aa911fd24920 8ee1b05f-2473-4c37-bfc5-ae393921b939)
```

to be able to print:

```
$  printf '%s\n' "${owner[@]}"

390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
0a452389-5ed2-e46f-ad15-cc538c82650d
4232f23d-ed48-4b14-c0ea-aa911fd24920
8ee1b05f-2473-4c37-bfc5-ae393921b939
```

And then, filter them as needed:

```
$ printf '%s\n' "${owner[@]}" | sort -u
0a452389-5ed2-e46f-ad15-cc538c82650d
390920ad-2858-e651-a4af-a9eaa6acaebb
4232f23d-ed48-4b14-c0ea-aa911fd24920
8ee1b05f-2473-4c37-bfc5-ae393921b939
e14c2413-7179-44f8-dfc3-b8624dcb10bb
```

And to get an array of values in the var uniq, do:

```
$ uniq=( $(printf '%s\n' "${owner[@]}" | sort -u) )
```

All the above works because the default IFS is .
If IFS change, the result may also change.